# How do I access the properties of a generic object by index in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, generics, typescript-generics, index-signature

I have the following function that goes through all the attributes of an object and converts them from ISO strings to Dates:

```
function findAndConvertDates<T>(objectWithStringDates: T): T {

    for (let key in Object.keys(objectWithStringDates)) {

        if (ISO_REGEX.test(objectWithStringDates[key])) {
            objectWithStringDates[key] = new Date(objectWithStringDates[key]);

        } else if (typeof objectWithStringDates[key] === 'object') {
            objectWithStringDates[key] = findAndConvertDates(
                objectWithStringDates[key]
            );
        }
    }
    return objectWithStringDates;
}
```

TypeScript keeps telling me that `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature` - referring to the numerous instances of `objectWithStringDates[key]`.

Considering that the object is passed in as a generic object, how would I set about accessing these properties without an explicit index signature?

(otherwise how do I supply an index signature or suppress this error?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make an indexable signature like this:

`function findAndConvertDates<T extends { [key: string]: any }>(objectWithStringDates: T): T {`

Comment: I tried this `export interface IGApiResponse<T extends {[key:string] : any}> extends GaxiosResponse<T> {}; let tmpData: IGApiResponse<GoogleApiSchema>; ` But when trying to get one of the property of tmp data, I got error of type script : ` const test = tmpData.data["test"] ` error : `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'`. If I add `any`, no errors, but not type safe...` const test =( tmpData.data as any)["test"]`